# How might I fix my java databasing error?

Tags: java, database

I've narrowed down my problem to these lines of code and I know it has something to do with the syntax. The error i get is: **[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in field definition** the section of code I get the error from is:

```
try {

            System.out.println("Creating StockTrades table...");
            stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE StockTrades (userID TEXT(20) CONSTRAINT FK1_StockTrades REFERENCES "
                                + "Users (userID), symbol TEXT(8), CONSTRAINT FK2_StockTrades FOREIGN KEY (symbol) "
                                + "REFERENCES Stocks (symbol), numStocks INT, pricePerStock DECIMAL(5, 2), "
                                + "stocksPurchased INT, stocksSold INT, totalCashPaid DECIMAL(9, 2), "
                                + "totalCashReceived DECIMAL(9, 2))");

        } catch(Exception ex) {

            System.out.println("Exception creating StockTrades table: " + ex.getMessage());

        }

        try {

            System.out.println("Creating StockTrades table primary key index...");
            stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PK_StockTrades ON StockTrades (userID, symbol) "
                                + "WITH PRIMARY DISALLOW NULL");

        } catch(Exception ex) {

            System.out.println("Exception creating StockTrades index: " + ex.getMessage());

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: To save people from reading through all the comments, this issue was solved by switching from a Decimal field type to the Currency type. The underlying issue was never identified or solved for those who can't switch away from the decimal type.

If I were to guess, I'd say it's this line:

```
symbol TEXT(8), CONSTRAINT FK2_StockTrades FOREIGN KEY
```

It seems you have an extra comma between text(8) and the constraint.

Edit: I had posted this just before the other poster then voted to delete. After researching it, you can do it either way, with or without the comma. However, you have it done both ways in consecutive lines. Perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: No thats not it either. It has something to do with the lines after that, because if I exclude everything but the userID and symbol foreign key it works just fine.

Comment: The only other thing with your syntax would seem to be if the other table isn't named "Stocks" or if that table lacks a column named "symbol." Everything else looks fine in that sql.

Comment: Both of the tables referenced exist and have the columns requested, also they are all spelled properly as well. So its baffling to have this problem, thats why I think the error is in the other columns of this table.

Comment: What does it mean that you have the word FOREIGN KEY attached to your second constraint but not your first? That's the only other discrepancy I see. After that, it's down to pulling columns out one at a time and dropping the table afterward. Best of luck!

Comment: Well the word FOREIGN KEY identifies the type of key the column in the parentheses is. That portion of code is only necessary when there is a comma between the constrained column and the constraint itself.

Comment: well, might I suggest running a base "create table" script and then several alter tables adding each column? And is there more to the error than just that one line? Google results seems to relate that error to anything from not having ODBC correctly configured to issues with the Decimal data type in a specific version of Access. Also, I've not used Access in years, but is it possible that you should be using the currency column type to prevent rounding errors?

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I needed to do to fix this problem. I appreciate all of the help and advice you have given me.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Out of curiosity, which was it - the decimal data type, the odbc configuration, or switching to currency? I'll edit my answer with the final verdict so anyone who happens to see this thread doesn't have to sift through our conversation. :)

Comment: I needed to switch to a currency data type for the problem to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE StockTrades (userID TEXT(20) CONSTRAINT FK1_
                                         ^---
```

missing comma?

Comment: No thats not it I've already checked for that. I sure wish it was though, it would make doing this easier.